# MouseOver title issue

Tags: html, jstl

Hello all I want to place all the contents of a `<td>` cell into a mouseOver.  Im currently doing a forEach to populate the cells with elements.  Some cells have an array of elements in it.  I want whats in the cell to also be what comes up on the MouseOver.  Im not sure how to format the title= to accomodate.

```
<table align="center" class="data_extract vert_scroll_table" >
    <tr>
        <c:forEach var="heading" items="${results.headings}"> 
            <th class="data_extract">${heading}</th>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${results.data}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="cell" items="${row}" varStatus="rowStatus">
                <td class="data_extract">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
                            <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
                                <span class="mouseover_text" title="${elem},&nbsp;">${elem}<c:if test="${!cellStatus.last}">,&nbsp;</c:if></span>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            ${cell}
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

I basically want after the loop is done here:

```
<c:when test="${results.types[rowStatus.index].array}">
    <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
        ${elem}<c:if test="${!cellStatus.last}">,&nbsp;</c:if>
    </c:forEach>
```

To put the results here in the title:

```
<span class="mouseover_text" title=  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, the title tag in your span tag is not getting generated properly.

See if the below code suits your problem. If not please explain it little bit more clearly.

```
 <c:forEach var="elem" items="${cell}" varStatus="cellStatus">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${cellStatus.count ==1}>
            <c:set var="temp" value="${elem}"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:set var="temp" value="${temp}, ${elem}"/>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <span class="mouseover_text" title="${temp}">${elem}<c:if test="${!cellStatus.last}">,&nbsp;</c:if></span>
</c:forEach>
```